# Monte Carlo integration &expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm confused as to how evaluating the Monte Carlo integration is the same as estimating
the expected value. For example, if $x \sim$ unif[0,1], why does $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx = E(f(x)) ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me call the function $g$ to avoid confusion with the probability density.

You know that for any variable $X$ with density $f_X(x)$ we have

$$E[X] = \int x f_X(x)dx \tag 1$$
and also

$$E[g(X)] = \int g(x) f_X(x) dx \tag 2$$

In particular, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ then

$$E[g(X)] = \int_0^1 g(x) dx \tag 3$$

You also know that, under some conditions, for large $n$ the expectation of a variable can be approximated by the sample average:

$$E[Y] \approx \frac{Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots Y_n}{n} \tag 4$$

where $Y_1, Y_2 \cdots Y_n$ are samples of $Y$
(for the precise meaning of that $\approx$, and the conditions that $Y$ must fullfill, see
the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers); in particular, it's sufficient that $Y$ is bounded)

Then, letting $Y=g(X)$ we conclude

$$\int_0^1 g(x) dx \approx \frac{g(X_1)+g(X_2) \cdots g(X_n)}{n}$$

and we can approximate an integral by averaging over random samples of the function (Montecarlo integration).